# Custom AuthenticationProvider not being called. Error 404

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have the following AuthenticationProvider:

```
@Component
public class RestAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)
            throws AuthenticationException {
        String name = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
        // do nothing for now
        //
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(name, password);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }

}
```

**SecurityConfig:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private RestAuthenticationProvider authProvider;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .eraseCredentials(true)
                .authenticationProvider(authProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                // permitir siempre
                .antMatchers("/", "/favicon.ico", "/resources/**", "/signup", "/about").permitAll()
                // All remaining URLs require that the user be successfully authenticated
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                // Setup form based authentication using the Java configuration defaults. Authentication is performed when a POST is submitted to the URL “/login” with the parameters “username” and “password”.
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/signin")
                .permitAll()
                .failureUrl("/signin?error=1")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticate")
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .permitAll()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/signin?logout")
                .and()
                .rememberMe()
                .and()
                .authenticationProvider(authProvider)
        ;
    }

}
```

configure should be enough but the **authenticate** method is never called. The strange thing is this was working last night, I don't know what changed.

And the form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Sign In</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <link href="../../../resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" th:href="@{/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css}"/>
    <link href="../../../resources/css/core.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" th:href="@{/resources/css/core.css}" />
</head>
<body>
<div th:replace="fragments/layout :: header"></div>
<form class="form-narrow form-horizontal" action="#" method="post" th:action="@{/authenticate}">
    <th:block th:if="${param.error != null}">
        <div th:replace="fragments/components :: alert (type='danger', message='Sign in error. Please try again.')">Alert</div>
    </th:block>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Please Sign In</legend>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Username</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Username" name="username" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPassword" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Password</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password" name="password" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="_spring_security_remember_me" /> Remember me
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
<div th:replace="fragments/layout :: footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**configure** and **configure** are being called. And **authProvider** is not null.

The login form is shown. Then I put user/name I get the following error:

http://xxxx:8080/mssgui/authenticate

**HTTP ERROR 404**

Comment: Is the login working, if you remove the custom provider? Test it, because 404 seems to have nothing to do with your custom provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was another thing. 404 was about the error handler that was missing. The error (visible in chrome developer console ) was:

*spring Could not verify the provided CSRF token because your session was not found.*